# RX Java multiple subscriptions

Tags: android, rx-java

Imagine you need to load and save some Data in one of your Fragments.

I want to use RX Java. How do you deal with multiple subscriptions on one Fragment ? AndroidObservable.bindFragment does the Job. But how can i use it when i need more subscriptions ?

```
public class MyFragment extends SomeFragment implements Observer<List<Item>>
{

private Subscription mReadSubscription;

private Subscription mWriteSubscription;

private JSONLoader mLoader;

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    final File theFile = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(), FILE_NAME);
    mLoader = new JSONLoader(theFile);
    mReadSubscription = mLoader.getReadSubscription(this);
    mWriteSubscription = mLoader.createWriteSubscription(new WriteObserver(), Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
```

The idea behind this is to save and load items using loader.load() loader.save(), each of this will result in an observer being used (mReadSubscription,mWriteSubscription).

The WriteObserver is just a simple Bean implementing the Observer again, but there is the part i do not understand: The #bindFragment Method checks for instances of Fragment. As WriteObserver is not an Fragment i cause an Exception. **But i cant register a second observer because of Generics**.

Im pretty sure i know to less about RX, anyone can point me in in a right direction to solve this ?

[Update 1]

There is my WriteObserver:

```
private final class WriteObserver implements Observer<Void> {


    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Save Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Void aVoid) {
    }
}
```

That design isn't working as WriteObserver is not a Fragment, cause an Exception when you doing:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target fragment is neither a native nor support library Fragment



AndroidObservable.bindFragment(observer, source)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(observer);
```

So, how can i get around that limitation ?

Comment: I updated my response after your update.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, `mLoader#getReadSubscription()` and `mLoader#createWriteSubscription()` creates steams and subscribe to it.

I don't think that the right way to do it, as if mLoader subscribe to streams, it should deal how to unsubscribe to it too.

As you want to use `AndroidObservable.bindFragment`, `mLoader#getReadSubscription()` and `mLoader#createWriteSubscription()` should return `Observable` and not `Subscription`.

So, in your fragment, you'll be able to write :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // [...]
   Observable<?> readObs = mLoader.getReadSubscription();
   mReadSubscription = AndroidObservable.bindFragment(this, readObs).subscribe(this);

   Observable<?> writeObs =  mLoader.createWriteSubscription(Collections.emptyList());
   mWriteSubscription = AndroidObservable.bindFragment(this, writeObs).subscribe(new WriteObserver());
}
```

> So, how can i get around that limitation ?

It's not a limitation.

```
 public static <T> Observable<T> bindFragment(Object fragment, Observable<T> source) {
      // ...
 }
```

The first argument **should be** your fragment, not your Observer. That why you should write your code as :

```
yourSubscription = AndroidObservable.bindFragment(yourFraglebt, yourObservable).subscribe(yourObserver);
```

so in your case :

```
AndroidObservable.bindFragment(this, source) // as bindFragment observeOn mainThread, you can remove the observeOn method call
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(observer);
```

and not

```
AndroidObservable.bindFragment(observer, source)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(observer);
```